# Django: How to add data to 2 tables at the same time

Tags: python, django, database

Having the following table models, I would like to write data from the form to 2 tables at the same time.

```
class Order(models.Model):
     department = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     responsible = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     month = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default=0)
     year = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default=0)
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.department)


class Article(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0, default=0)
     order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Order")
     comments = description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.name)
```

view is now very simple:

```
def new_order(request):
    form_order = OrderForm(request.POST or None)

    order_Date = datetime.now()
    add_date_month = order_Date.strftime("%m")
    add_date_year = order_Date.strftime("%Y")

    if form_order.is_valid():
        form_order.instance.month = request.POST.get('date_month')
        form_order.instance.year = request.POST.get('date_year')
        form_order.save()
        return redirect(orders)

    context = {
        'form_order': form_order,
        'date_month': add_date_month,
        'date_year': add_date_year,
    }

    return render(request, 'supplier/new_order.html', context)
```

Currently, there may be a bug in the code because I am wandering trying to change an existing larger project. Previously, I saved articles as separate items. At the moment I would like to group them in orders.

I would like a new order to be created simultaneously when the user adds the first item. Then the user would add articles to this order and the data would be saved in one table.
In addition, each item would have to have the ID of the order to which it was assigned. In the case of subsequent articles, there will be no problem, how to add this ID to the first added article?

My question is: ***How to write data to 2 tables at once?***

Comment: Can you share the view that is currently already creating the `Order`?

Answer (score 0):

Using class-based views, base them on one model but add fields relevant to the other model if necessary:

```
class MyForm( forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['foo', 'bar', ...]

    other_baz = forms.CharField( ... )  # for another model
    ...
```

In the view, attend to the other model in form_valid

```
def form_valid( self, form):
    instance = form.save( commit = False) 
    other_instance = OtherModel.objects.get( ...)
    other_instance.baz = forms.cleaned_data['other_baz']

    with transaction.atomic():  # save both or neither
        instance.save()
        other_instance.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect( ...)
```

In a create view where you wish to create a foreignkey to the newly created instance

```
with transaction.atomic():
    new_instance = form.save( commit = False) 
    new_instance.save()           # won't have a pk until saved
    other_instance = OtherModel()
    ...
    other_instance.fk_field = new_instance
    other_instance.save()

return HttpResponseRedirect( ...)
```